# Ms access - remove duplicates from one column

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

A query returns data in the following format

```
-----------------------------------------
| CustID | ProdID | Date       | Amount |
-----------------------------------------
| 001    | 444    | 12/09/2017 | £234   |
| 001    | 524    | ....       | £234   |
| 004    | 444    | ....       | £321   |
| 008    | 523    | .....      | £299   |
| 008    | 444    | ...        | £299   |
.......
```

As shown above, there are often multiple records for CustID (one per ProdID). The problem is that the amount in the last column is the total for **both** 444 and 524 (in the case of Customer 001). Additionally, the ProdId can contain duplicates as the products are the same for many customers.

In other words, in Excel speak, I'm trying to remove duplicates from column CustID.

I'd like it to be:

```
-------------------
| CustID | Amount | 
-------------------
| 001    | £234   |
| 004    | £321   | 
| 008    | £299   |
```

Comment: Check how to use `groupBy` It  will help you have the duplicates removed

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT CustID, Amount FROM MyTable` or `SELECT CustID, Amount FROM MyTable GROUP BY CustID` should do it.  [Distinct](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-24f2a47d-a803-4c7c-8e81-756fe298ce57) & [Group By](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/group-by-clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0)

Comment: Great. It's worked.